# Edit Work Item Templates in Visual Studio Teamservices?

Tags: tfs-workitem, azure-devops

Is it possible to edit the Work Item Templates (former TFS Online) in Visual Studio Team Services?

I haven't found anything yet during my research. I tried the Powertools, unfortunately it says "access denied".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a new Process Template inherited from an existing one, then add customisations to that.

The easiest way to get started is to open a Work Item and click on the "..." on the top right and select Customize:

[image: Customise Work Item]

There are lots of details I have found via the documentation on [visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/overview-of-get-started-tasks-vs)  - [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/process/customize-process) or on this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/12/10/adding-a-custom-field-to-a-work-item/).

Comment: I saw the Customize button (but the field "State" is readonly, so I cant change it. Further more I have tried to Export the process template, unfortunately I wasnt able to find any useful file in there. I would like to edit the Work Item Templates and not the Process Template :)

Comment: @Jannik you cannot use the existing Process Template editor tools with VSTS, there is a new process for customising work items, if the feature you require isn't there, it probably hasn't been built/shipped yet by the VS team. I'm sure they will add more features soon.

Comment: @Jannik if you require a new state, have you considered using the Kanban boards to customise states instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Work/kanban/kanban-basics ?